# Open client mail Outlook with "mailto" work only in debug mode but not after deployed on "localhost"

Tags: c#, asp.net, email, smtp, mailto

Hello here is my problem I face for a while. I do not understand why, but opening the email client does not work after deployed my web application on my post localhost.But however everything works in debug mode from visual studio!

Thank you in advance for your help;-)

Here is my simple code:

```
try
{
    string dataBaseName = string.Empty;
    string serverName = ttbx_ServerName.Text;
    //get item from radcombobox to make the body message
    foreach (RadComboBoxItem item in cbx_DbName.Items)
    {
        if (item.Checked)
        {
            dataBaseName += "[#] : " + item.Text + "\n";
        }
    }

    string Body = "Last name: " + ttbx_YourName.Text + "\nFirst name: " + ttbx_YourFirstName.Text + "\nServer Name: " + serverName + "\nDataBase(s) name: \n" + dataBaseName + "\nSID: " + getMd5Hash(ttbx_sidSqlServer.Text);
    string command = "mailto:register@arms.ch?subject=A.R.M.S%20Customer%20Key%20Request&body=" + Body.Replace("\n", "%0D%0A");
    Process.Start(command);
}
catch (Exception)
{
    lbl_Error.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
    lbl_Error.Text = "No smtp mail client found , please send manually the informations";
    lbl_Error.Visible = true;
}
```

Comment: Seriously? You want to open the mail client on the web server instead of the client?

Comment: just wanted to open the mail client at the click of a button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot execute the process (Process.Start) on the client because it will be thru web interface. It works in debug because it starts the process on your local computer but won't work with "real" clients.

Instead you have to display a mailto link in your browser like this :

```
<a href="mailto:admin@domain.com?subject=" + subjectFromCode + " id="email-link">Send Email</a>
```

**Edit**

If you want to programmatically run this you can do ti thru jquery :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("#email-link").click();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

When deployed, the Process.Start will attempt to run the email client under the user account of whatever account the IIS process is tunning under.  This will most likely not be the same as the logged in user account so you would not see the email client run.

To be honest, I am not entirely sure why you are trying to run an email client from a web app, I am struggling to see how this would work.

If you want the web site user to see the email client running, you need the mailto HTML element in the actual web page on the client.

Using asp.net this could be a control like this

```
<asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink1" runat="server" NavigateUrl = "" Text = ""></asp:HyperLink>
```

Then in your code behind, in the PageLoad you could set the NavigateUrl using the email address, subject and body you need.

Comment: Then you advise me to use a javascript call with "mailto" in html ? To be sure opening and call function are client side and not server side? Sorry i speak not very good english

Comment: You need a mailto, as in Amo2501's answer.  But you need to generate it server side, so that you can add in the email subject and body.

Comment: Yess thanks a lot . I have done that 
Create a "HyperLink" an Html Page. And after
hyperLink_mailto.NavigateUrl = command;
And call a javascript method for auto click on hyperlink $("#email-link").click();